# b.javascript_dialog().exists? is not working for me in WATIR 4.0.2

Tags: ruby, watir

When I execute the code

```
b.javascript_dialog().exists?
```

it works fine in WATIR 3.0.0 but it's throwing the following error in WATIR 4.0.2, Why it is so? Have they given any other function corresponding to "javascript_dialog()"?

hello.rb:8:in `<main>': undefined method`javascript_dialog' for # (NoMethodError)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [changelog for v3.1.0](https://github.com/watir/watir-classic/blob/193ef19fce422683a3742d0b222cd9024b795027/CHANGES#L77):

> Remove Browser#(javascript_)dialog. Use Browser#alert API instead.

The `javascript_dialog` has been replaced by `alert`:

```
b.alert.exists?
```